# How can I know if a piano is worth saving? I am a repurposer of old woods

Tags: piano

I am a certified master repurposer, and I want to disassemble old pianos in order to repurpose the beautiful woods and workings, but I don't want to take apart a piano that still has a musical future. So many are available for free; so many go to the dump. Very sad.

I see some hints elsewhere on this site. Any more clues?

Thanks in advance. If you want to see what artisans are doing with disassembled pianos, go to pinterest and look at https://www.pinterest.com/pin/522417625498172672/

Comment: Dear SE: Just because there's a link to a site doesn't make it spam. This question does not "exist onloy to promote a product or service" and should not be closed, in my opinion. Too often good questions are flagged down because of a minor issue like this one.

Comment: @user45266 - common sense should prevail. It often does here. The ideas are very interesting! Thanks, OP.

Comment: Anything is better than going to the dump!! If you have the means of moving pianos you can charge people to pick up free pianos and deliver them to their house. This is how we got our free piano, paid to have it moved. If you don't know anything about pianos it might to be hard to tell at first glance if it worth saving.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind spending a little money, find a piano tuner or repairman and pay a chunk of $$ to have them tell you what the restoration cost would be and what the final value would be.  You can then decide for yourself how you feel about dismantling each piano.

I can tell you that the vast majority of pianos that you can get for small cash are either beyond hope or never much good to begin with.  Unlike, say, top-notch string instruments, new pianos have great sound the moment they leave the factory, and hundreds if not thousands are produced every year, so I wouldn't worry too much about zombifying older ones.

Comment: I can agree except when encountering instruments from before 1900 since salvageable pianos from before then are quite rare (and the older the rarer) and important historical sources.

Answer (score 0):

If the tuning pinblock, bridge, soundboard, and bass strings are intact it may be worth saving.  Not necessarily for a profit, but if there is the possibility of tuning, it might be valuable still.

Comment: I think the point is: how does the OP evaluate these?